# Loading netbeans generated .jar's into matlab fails

Tags: java, matlab, netbeans

I'm trying to get a "Hello World" like java project to be used in matlab. To start easy, I tried to make a simple netbeans project containing only 1 file with some basic functions to test.
[image]

With "HelloWorld.java" being:

```
public class HelloWorld{

        public HelloWorld(){
                setVersion(0);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }

        public void setVersion(int aVersion){
                if( aVersion < 0 ){
                    System.err.println("Improper version specified.");
                }
                else{
                        version = aVersion;
                }
        }

        public int getVersion(){
                return version;
        }

        private int version;

}
```

I built this in netbeans to create a .jar, but when trying to connect to it in matlab via the following code it cannot find HelloWorld when trying to make an object.

```
javaaddpath('C:\Users\<name>\Documents\Netbeans\HelloWorld\dist\HelloWorld.jar')

javaclasspath

myHelloObject = HelloWorld
```

It gives the following error

```
Undefined function or variable 'HelloWorld'.

Error in test (line 6)
myHelloObject = HelloWorld
```

However, when using "example jars" that I downloaded of the internet and connected them in matlab via the same method this seems to work, so I guess there is something wrong with the .jar generation.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Already found the answer: it had to do with Matlab using java 1.7 while the jar was generated in 1.8. Switching to another virtual machine (or generating the jar in another java version) solves the problems. https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/130359-how-do-i-change-the-java-virtual-machine-jvm-that-matlab-is-using-on-windows